# Replace the value in appSettings key without making multiple web.config files

Tags: asp.net, web-config, appsettings

I have a key in appSettings of web.config file as follows:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="connectionString" value="my_dev_connectionString"/>
</appSettings>
```

and I want to replace this value in Production Environment with "my_production_connectionString" but I DO NOT want to create multiple web.config files like web.test.config and web.production.config. 
How do i do that?
Is there a way I can replace this value in the Release definitions of the Visual Studio project?

Comment: Google web.config transforms.  Also, consider ConfigSections.